# How to paint an object like this?

Tags: texturing, materials

Is there a way to do this without selecting every vertex to change the material to gold?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: use a MixRGB in order to mix several Image Texture nodes, and use their alpha output as factor (or a b&w image)

Comment: How do I do the gold part?

Comment: I’m kind of a beginner, do you recommend any YouTube video for this? Thanks alot :)

Comment: mix a Principled BSDF with another one (or Glossy node with a Principled) in a Mix Shader, and a b&w picture as factor

Answer (score 3):

You can mix a white *Diffuse* with a yellow *Glossy* node, in a *Mix Shader*, with a b&w image texture mask as factor, paint this b&w image:

[image]

If you have a second layer (red painting), create a second *Mix Shader* after the first one, and same thing, use a second *Image Texture* as mask:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate it!

Comment: you're welcome, tell if you meet a problem

Comment: I dont want to paint it freehand, like maybe like on mask? How to go about with that?

Comment: you can do it in another software if you export the UV as layer, and yes you can create a b&w mask as well